# Value from one table on basis of another table

Tags: mysql, database

I have two table as table1 and table2 given below:

[image]

[image]

I want to have the value of only those table_name from table1 which has there id in print_table column in table 2.

I have implemented the following query but it returns only one value:

```
SELECT * FROM print_tabel_permission_admin WHERE id IN (select print_table from secondary)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.table_name
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON FIND_IN_SET(t1.id, t2.print_table) > 0;
```

[image]

### Demo

You should probably move away from storing CSV data in your tables like this.  Instead, break out the IDs in `table2` onto separate rows.  This will make your life easier.